# PrincipalContext fails under Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, principalcontext

```
pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

Using this statement under Windows 8 produces the exception:

> The server could not be contacted.

The user is already logged in to the machine when this is hit. It's running under WinForms. It works fine under Windows 7. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it really? That is interesting, going to test....

Comment: Have you checked if Windows 8 firewall is blocking outgoing connections from your application?

Comment: No, I didn't think I would have to...I will though. That will really suck if that's the issue considering it works without issue under Windows 7. Telling all our customers they have to change this will basically kill the use of this.